# Alternatives for Sys.getTime() and Sys.getTimerResolution()?

Tags: java, lwjgl

In my client (using LWJGL), I use the following code:

```
private static long getTime() {
    return (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution(); 
}
```

However, I have also just finished coding a server for this game, and up until now, I am been using LWJGL **only for the purpose of having that method in my code**. Which really, is a bit impractical.

What is a suitable alternative for the above code that uses no libraries at all?

Comment: http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_4_%28Timing%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for `System.nanoTime()` in the Java libraries. This method would obviously give you a `long` of the time, of which you could standardize into ticks.

```
// beginning of the game loop
long startTime = System.nanoTime();    


// end of the game loop 
long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

You could divide this number by the amount of ticks you want per second (as `Sys.getTimerResolution()` does) and then you could have very similar operation to what the `LWJGL` library provides you.